# Would it be useful to cram the <title> element full of relevant keywords? What are the downsides of this practice?

Tags: html, seo

I've read at many places that the title of web page must be *concise* and *informative*. I've also read that user agents use the *title* as the foremost thing to index the web pages. So wouldn't the web page get more hits if we add many keywords in the title element?

What are the downsides and upsides of this practice?

P.S: Note that I am talking about `<title>` element of html lagnguage.

Answer (score 2):

No...in fact you could get severely penalized for that. The term for that is "keyword stuffing." I would strongly advise against it as it's a black hat SEO technique. You can read more here: http://www.webopedia.com/TERM/B/Black_Hat_SEO.html

It's better to pick good keywords than just use a bunch in your title - quality over quantity here.

Comment: Thank you for telling the term "Keyword stuffing". I've no intentions to wear the black hat. I just encountered the question in the tutorial https://www.w3.org/community/webed/wiki/The_HTML_head_element#Exercise_questions

Comment: Is "keyword stuffing" about repeating same keyword or using unnecessary keyword in the meta tags?